# Why does cURL give correct response but scrapy does not?

Tags: python, curl, scrapy

Why does cURL give correct response but scrapy does not?

The site I want to scrape using javascript to fill in a form then POSTs it and verifies before serving the content.

I've replicated this js in python, after scraping the parameters from the javascript in the initial GET request. My value of **"TS644333_75"** matches the js value (as tested by doing a document.write(..) out, instead of letting it submit like normal), and if you copy and paste the result into cURL that works too. For example:

```
curl  --http1.0 'http://www.betvictor.com/sports/en/football' -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
 -H  'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en' 
 -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' 
 -H 'Referer: http://www.betvictor.com/sports/en/football' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0' 
--data 
'TS644333_id=3&
 TS644333_75=286800b2a80cd3334cd2895e42e67031%3Ayxxy%3A3N6QfX3q%3A1685704694&
 TS644333_md=1&
 TS644333_rf=0&
 TS644333_ct=0&
 TS644333_pd=0' --compressed
```

Where to get **TS644333_75** I've simply copy and pasted the result my python code calculated when simulating the js.

Monitoring packets in wireshark shows this POST as shown [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7124807/) (I've added some line spaces to make the POST data more readable, but otherwise it's as seen in wireshark).

However if I start a scrapy shell:

```
1) scrapy shell "http://www.betvictor.com/sports/en/football"
```

and construct a form request:

```
2) from scrapy.http import FormRequest

   req=FormRequest(
    url='http://www.betvictor.com/sports/en/football',
    formdata={
              'TS644333_id': '3',
              'TS644333_75': '286800b2a80cd3334cd2895e42e67031:yxxy:3N6QfX3q:1685704694',
              'TS644333_md': '1',
              'TS644333_rf': '0',
              'TS644333_ct': '0',
              'TS644333_pd': '0'
    },
    headers={
    'Referer': 'http://www.betvictor.com/sports/en/football',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
   }
   )
```

Then fetch it

```
3) fetch(req)
```

The response body I get back is just another javascript challenge, not the served up content desired.

Yet the packet seen in wireshark is (again with some newlines for readability in POST params)
shown [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7124827/), and to my eyes looks **indentical**
.

What is going wrong? How can packets that appear identical lead to different server responses? Why is this not working with scrapy?

It could be the encoding of the ":" in the parameter computed that I POST, but it looks to have been encoded correctly, and both match in wireshark, so I can't see that as the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to work if you append a slash to your URL - so same scrapy request, but with URL changed to:

```
http://www.betvictor.com/sports/en/football/
```

**Additional Example:**

I had the same problem when testing another website where the page worked on `curl` nicely, but did not work with `requests`. After fighting with it for sometime, this answer with extra slash solved the problem.

```
import requests
import json


r = requests.get(r'https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/getJSON.aspx/?sd=20190101&ed=20190331&sb=0')

pretty_json = json.loads(r.text)
print (json.dumps(pretty_json, indent=2))
```

returns this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "19/037",
       "date": "30/03/2019",
        "no": "15+17+18+37+39+49",
        "sno": "31",
        "sbcode": "",
...
...
```

The slash after  .aspx is important. It doesn't work without it. Without the slash, the page returns an empty javascript challenge.

```
import requests
import json

#no slash
    r = requests.get(r'https://bet.hkjc.com/marksix/getJSON.aspx?sd=20190101&ed=20190331&sb=0')

    print(r.text)
```

returns this:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
Challenge=341316;
ChallengeId=49424326;
GenericErrorMessageCookies="Cookies must be enabled in order to view this page.";
</script>
<script>
function test(var1)
{
    var var_str=""+Challenge;
    var var_arr=var_str.split("");
    var LastDig=var_arr.reverse()[0];
    var minDig=var_arr.sort()[0];
    var subvar1 = (2 * (var_arr[2]))+(var_arr[1]*1);
    var subvar2 = (2 * var_arr[2])+var_arr[1];
    var my_pow=Math.pow(((var_arr[0]*1)+2),var_arr[1]);
    var x=(var1*3+subvar1)*1;
    var y=Math.cos(Math.PI*subvar2);
    var answer=x*y;
    answer-=my_pow*1;
    answer+=(minDig*1)-(LastDig*1);
    answer=answer+subvar2;
    return answer;
}
</script>
<script>
client = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    var client=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        client = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    };
}
if (!((!!client)&&(!!Math.pow)&&(!!Math.cos)&&(!![].sort)&&(!![].reverse)))
{
    document.write("Not all needed JavaScript methods are supported.<BR>");

}
else
{
    client.onreadystatechange  = function()
    {
        if(client.readyState  == 4)
        {
            var MyCookie=client.getResponseHeader("X-AA-Cookie-Value");
            if ((MyCookie == null) || (MyCookie==""))
            {
                document.write(client.responseText);
                return;
            }

            var cookieName = MyCookie.split('=')[0];
            if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName)==-1)
            {
                document.write(GenericErrorMessageCookies);
                return;
            }
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    };
    y=test(Challenge);
    client.open("POST",window.location,true);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-ID', ChallengeId);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-Result',y);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge',Challenge);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' , 'text/plain');
    client.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>JavaScript must be enabled in order to view this page.</noscript>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Many thanks. If anyone knows why this final '/' is required in python requests lib and in scrapy but not cURL, I'd be really interested in hearing the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that the order of the parameters really mattered for this server (I guess because it was simulating a hidden form with ordered inputs, and this was an extra validation check). In python requests using a POST str and url encoding by hand (i.e. `':' --> '%3A'`) makes things work. So although the wireshark packets are near enough identical, the only way they differ is the param string order, and indeed this is the key.

In `Scrapy` passing a tuple like:

```
 ot=     ( ('TS644333_id', '3'),
              ('TS644333_75', value),
              ('TS644333_md', '1'),
              ('TS644333_rf', '0'),
              ('TS644333_ct', '0'),
              ('TS644333_pd', '0')
             )
```

to `formdata=` rather than a dictionary, so that order is preserved works too.

Also the header `{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` is required.

As `anana` noted in his answer, appending a trailing '/' to all request URLs also fixes things, in fact you can get away with just GET requests alone, with no js simulation and no form POSTing if you do this!